# SPARQL property path query

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I'm trying to use SPARQL 1.1 property paths with VirtuosoOS 6.1 but something is wrong. I use the next graph:

```
@prefix foo: <foo/> .
@prefix bar: <bar/> .
@prefix type: <type/> .

bar:a1 type:read foo:b1 .
bar:a1 type:write foo:b2 .
bar:a1 type:write foo:b3 .
bar:a2 type:read foo:b4 .
bar:a2 type:write foo:b5 .
bar:a3 type:write foo:b6 .
foo:b2 type:link foo:b4 .
foo:b4 type:link foo:b6 .
```

I want to find all "linked" "foo"s that start from x, where x is bar:a1 ---(type:write)--> x. Obviously the answer is foo:b4 and foo:b6.

So, I use this query

```
prefix bar: <bar/>
prefix type: <type/>

select ?y where {
    bar:a1 type:write ?x .
    ?x type:link+ ?y
}
```

But Virtuoso says

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 8: syntax error at '?y' before '}'
```

What is wrong with my query? Maybe Virtuoso doesn't support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether your query is legal syntax with the [query validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  Your query is well-formed, so this is an issue with Virtuoso support.  According to [Does Virtuoso versions <=6.0 support SPARQL 1.1?](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/11843/does-virtuoso-versions-60-support-sparql-11), you can get SPARQL 1.1 support through extensions in earlier versions, and that 6.2 and onward support SPARQL 1.1 without need for extensions.  According to the official [Virtuoso Open-Source Edition](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/) page, it looks like versions 6.1.7 and 7.0.0 should have support for property paths.

Comment: Yes, it is said that 6.1.7 supports sparql 1.1. that is why I got confused about this query. Thanks for answer.